# jquery find: selector can not reference calling element

Tags: jquery

i am noticing a bug in jquery find.

if i call foo.find with a selector that might reference foo itself, it won't work. example here.

http://jsfiddle.net/CgfPj/6/ (EDIT: UPDATED THE fiddle to more clearly explain what i'm trying to do)

test.find should be able to find a span that is a child of a div, but it can't seem to since the div is test itself. is this a bug?

Comment: This is expected behavior and not a bug!

Comment: Only descendants are considered candidates for the match. Your span isnt a descendant of test

Comment: it is a descendant of test. the span is a direct child of test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#test` is the `div` you're referencing.

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) returns the descendants of `#test` matching your given selector. `#test` has no descendant `div`s, hence `test.find("div > span")` doesn't match any elements.

To get the direct `span` descendants of `#test` you should use:

```
test.find("> span")
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/CgfPj/3/)

---

Edit as per OP edit:

```
$("#test > span, #test div > span")
```

Will get all `span`s direct descendant of `#test` as well as all `span` elements direct descendant of `div`s inside of `#test` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/CgfPj/7/).

There's no such thing as a `:parentIs(div)` selector in the CSS selectors spec nor in jQuery as far as I'm aware of, but you can easily fill that gap by using a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```
var spans = test.find('span').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent()[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div';
});

$("#result").text(spans.length);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/CgfPj/8/)

Comment: is "> span" the same as saying .children("span")? I'm trying to do something different. shouldnt the selector i did be looking for any spans that are direct children of divs, inside of test? the span inside test fits that selector

Comment: Guess I'll just rewrite the answer to match your edited question. Sec

Comment: `$("#test > span, #test div > span")` will get all `span`s direct descendant of `#test` as well as all span direct descendant of divs inside of `#test` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/CgfPj/7/). But it'd be nice to know what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i'd like to be able take an element, foo and say foo.find(selector) and return all spans inside foo that are children of divs, whether or not the div is foo itself. is the way foo.find("div > span") works that it looks for spans inside divs that are inside foo? not just spans that are inside foo and inside a div?

Comment: I'm afraid that there's no such thing as a parent selector, but stacking a `find` with a `filter` function should take care of that. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I am looking at this right..

```
var test = $("#test");
$("#result").text(test.find("div > span").length)
$("#result2").text($("div > span").length)​
```

By defining `test` as the element that is the div itself. Your essentially telling `find` to look for another div with a span in that div. Try

```
$("#result").text(test.find("span").length)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test">
  <span>hello</span>
</div>   

$("#result").text(test.find("div > span").length)
```

The Output that length = 0 is absolutely right.. That is not a bug but the expected behavior.

You span is nested inside the div with **#test**

`test.find("div > span")`  //  is trying to find a span which is a child of div nested inside #test div.. Because it has no div inside #test this will give you 0.

The HTML in this case which will return 1 is

```
<div id="test">
   <div>
      <span>hello</span>
   </div>
</div>
```